# PHP and MySqli getting all results

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 rows of data in my database and I am trying to fetch all rows

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select username, email, is_admin from adminUsers");

$results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

I have tried mysqli_fetch_assoc, mysqli_fetch_row, mysqli_fetch_array all of them just return 1 row of data.

Comment: Did you use a loop? (*nope*) - Too trivial.

Comment: you need to loop through `while ($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_*()` functions except `mysqli_fetch_all()`, if supported, fetch one row.  Loop and fetch:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    print_r($row);
    //or you can echo $row['username'] etc...
    //or store in an array to loop through later
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

If you use `mysqlnd` there is a `mysqli_fetch_all()` or use:

```
if(!function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) {
function mysqli_fetch_all($result, $resulttype=MYSQLI_BOTH) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, $resulttype)) {
        $rows[] =$row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
}

$results = mysqli_fetch_all($query);
```

But then you have to loop through all the returned rows anyway:

```
foreach($results as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    //or you can echo $row['username'] etc...
}
```

Comment: Only if you use `mysqlnd` I'm pretty sure.  Try it or see function in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

#### Switch to PDO to do it in a single go... Use [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
<?php

//.. Do the neccessary PDO connections...
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select username, email, is_admin from adminUsers");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

**(or)**

#### You need to loop through them... [**MySQLi**]

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select username, email, is_admin from adminUsers");
$res = array();
while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
 $res[] = $results;
}

print_r($res);
```

Comment: Thanks Dear Mate ! Since OP was particularly looking for a single line statement so thought of this :)

Comment: Same comment of @Fred -ii-.

Comment: If I may suggest though Shankar, that you keep (*put back in*) the code you originally had to fit the OP's present code, that way OP won't have to reconfigure everything to suit PDO connection ;-) Edit: Too late, OP chose the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`while`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop for fetching all lines:

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    // Rest of your code. See an example below
    echo $result['username'];
}
```